# Nueva política de privacidad, aplicaciones en la Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Ayer(6 de febrero de 2017) fui bombardeado con correos por parte de **Google Play Support**, que decían que mis aplicaciones tenían problemas con la **política de privacidad** y que si no se cambiaban se ocultarían.

La solución que ellos dan es la siguiente:

> **Añadir una política de privacidad a la página Ficha de Play Store**
>
> 1. Accede a [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
> 2. Selecciona una aplicación.
> 3. Selecciona la Ficha de Play Store.
> 4. En la sección "Política de Privacidad", introduce la URL en la que tengas alojada la política de privacidad online.
> 5. Selecciona Guardar borrador (aplicaciones nuevas) o Enviar actualización (aplicaciones actuales).

Hasta acá **no sé** como generar la url con las políticas de privacidad, entonces dejo dos preguntas **¿debo crear un sitio web y en él adjuntar las políticas de privacidad? ¿deben tener un algún formato en especial?**

Pero luego revise mi ficha de privacidad y me encontré con la siguiente alerta:

> Tu APK solicita los siguientes permisos:
>   android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS. Las aplicaciones que utilizan estos
>   permisos en un APK deben tener configurada una política de privacidad.

Yo **no** uso este permiso, pero sé que al usar la libreria GCM **com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0** se estaría llamando al permiso android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS. Creo que ya tengo "controlado" (o eso espero) este problema, agregando la siguiente línea en mi manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" tools:node="remove" />
```

Ahora, dejo la tercera y cuarta pregunta: Si añado esta linea en mi manifest **¿se solucionará el problema en la Play Store? ¿Afectará el funcionamiento de las notificaciones?** (en las pruebas que he realizado las notificaciones me llegan sin problema)

### ----------

Ya que esta lenta la cosa, EDITO para responderme sólo.

El tema de remover el permiso usando

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" tools:node="remove" />
```

En la documentación [GCM](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) se indica que es empleado para:

> Para dispositivos previos del a 4.0.4, la comunicación GCM requiere
>   que los usuarios configuren su cuenta de Google en sus dispositivos móviles, 
>   pero no es un requisito en los dispositivos que ejecutan Android 4.0.4 o superior (Nivel de API 15 o superior).

El remover el permiso ocasionaría problemas en versiones inferiores a la API 15, en mi caso definí `minSdkVersion 11` entonces, no debó remover el permiso y estoy obligado a vincular la política de privacidad...
Lamentablemente el permiso se mostrará en dispositivos iguales o superiores a API 15, que no necesitan del permiso. ¿hay forma de remover el permiso solo el dispositivos superiores a API 15?

Leer más sobre este tema en [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444227/get-accounts-permission-while-using-gcm-why-is-this-needed#18444343)

Resumen de Preguntas:

1. **¿hay forma de remover el permiso solo el dispositivos superiores a API 15?, es decir, un manifest distinto por versión Android**
2. **¿debo crear un sitio web y en él adjuntar las políticas de privacidad?**
3. **¿deben tener un algún formato en especial?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De acuerdo con sus páginas de [ayuda](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en&visit_id=1-636221579070601975-2918216429&rd=1#privacy), Google Play no obliga a tener una Política de privacidad, para su aplicación o juego Android. Se exigirá dependiendo del tipo de aplicación que se desarrolló.

> [**Política de privacidad de las aplicaciones de Android**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en&visit_id=1-636221579070601975-2918216429&rd=1#privacy)
>
> La adición de una política de privacidad al listado de la tienda de la aplicación brinda transparencia sobre cómo trata los datos de los usuarios y dispositivos sensibles.
>
> - **Para las aplicaciones que solicitan acceso a permisos o datos confidenciales** (como se definen en las políticas de datos de [usuario](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/user-data/)): *debe* vincular a una política de privacidad en la página de la tienda de la aplicación y en la aplicación . Asegúrese de que su política de privacidad está disponible en una URL activa, que se aplique a su aplicación y cubre específicamente la privacidad del usuario.
> - **Para aplicaciones del programa [Designed for Families](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/families/about.html)**: *debe* vincular a una política de privacidad en la página de la tienda de la aplicación y en la aplicación, independientemente del acceso de la aplicación a permisos o datos confidenciales. Asegúrese de que su política de privacidad está disponible en una URL activa, que se aplique a su aplicación y cubra específicamente la privacidad del usuario.
> - **Para otras aplicaciones**: *no es necesario* publicar una política de privacidad.
>
> **Agregue una política de privacidad a su ficha de tienda**
>
> 1. Accede a la consola de [Google Play para desarrolladores](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
> 2. Seleccione una  aplicación.
> 3. Seleccione Lista de tiendas.
> 4. En "Política de privacidad", ingrese la URL en la que tiene la política de privacidad alojada en línea.
> 5. Seleccione Guardar borrador (nuevas aplicaciones) o Enviar actualización (aplicaciones existentes).

Sin embargo, el acuerdo de distribución de Google para [desarrolladores](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html), que debe ser leído y aceptado al registrarse en una cuenta de Google Play, le informa que se le requiere que tenga "*procedimientos y avisos de privacidad en su lugar*".

**Un "aviso de privacidad" es un acuerdo de [Política de Privacidad](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html).**

> Usted acepta que si utiliza la Tienda para distribuir Productos,
> protegerá la privacidad y los derechos legales de los usuarios. Si los
> usuarios le proporcionan o su producto accede o utiliza nombres de
> usuario, contraseñas u otra información de acceso o información
> personal, debe informar a los usuarios de que la información estará
> disponible para su producto y debe proporcionar una información
> legalmente adecuada Aviso de privacidad y protección para esos
> usuarios.

Independientemente de la información de Google sobre esto, su aplicación Android está obligada (incluso por algunas leyes, como lo cita la *fuente 2* al final de la respuesta) a tener una Política de privacidad si se recopila datos personales de los usuarios, no importa si su aplicación es un simple webview o un juego móvil.Se requiere que una aplicación SaaS (Software-as-a-Services, en español software como servicio) tenga una Política de privacidad.

**Cómo agregar la URL de la Política de privacidad para la aplicación para Android**

Siga estos pasos para agregar la URL de la Política de privacidad a la lista de aplicaciones de Google Play Store:

1. Inicia sesión en la consola de Google Play para desarrolladores. Si
   no tiene una cuenta, cree una primera.
2. Seleccionar todas las aplicaciones
3. Seleccione la aplicación
4. Haga clic en Lista de tiendas
5. Ir al campo Política de privacidad
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. Introduzca la dirección URL en la que hospeda la política de privacidad (debe alojar la política en un sitio web).
7. Haga clic en Guardar

Si aún no tiene la Política de privacidad lista, puede hacer clic en "No enviar una URL de política de privacidad en este momento" en la página "Listado de tiendas".

Existen sitios que permiten crear las políticas de privacidad para aplicaciones móviles, uno de ellos es [**Iubenda**](https://www.iubenda.com/en/privacy-policy-generator/start_modal#generator_mobile_app_modal) y [**Termsfeed**](https://termsfeed.com/wizard/privacy-policy), herramienta que permite generar las políticas con una interfaz y diseño responsivo (lamentablemente ambos de pago).

**Herramientas analíticas del trafico de información (Google Analytics y similares)**

[image: google analytics]

Por ejemplo, si se utilizan herramientas de gestión como [Google Analytics](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-google-analytics/) , [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/legal-privacy/terms-service/flurry-analytics-terms-service) o [Fabric Answers](https://answers.io/img/privacy.pdf) (recientemente adquirida por google) para su aplicaciones, debe tener la Política de privacidad mencionada en el acuerdo de términos de servicio de Google Analytics:

> Debe publicar una Política de privacidad y dicha Política de
> privacidad debe proporcionar un aviso de sus datos que se recopilarán. **Debe revelar el uso** de Google Analytics, **cómo recopila** y **procesa los datos**.

**Aplicaciones con métodos de comunicación**

Estas aplicaciones incluyen:

- Correos electrónicos.
- Notificaciones push de dispositivos móviles.

Este tipo de aplicación **debe informar** de su uso en las políticas de privacidad.

**Ejemplos de políticas de privacidad de las aplicaciones de Android**

- **Youtube**
  La aplicación YouTube de YouTube de Google tiene un enlace de Política de privacidad y está disponible desde el listado de Play Store:

[image: aplicación youtube]

Al hacer clic en el enlace, el usuario es redirigido a la Política de privacidad de Google:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- **Flipboard**
  Otro ejemplo muestra cómo la [aplicación de Flipboard para Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app) enlaza con su [página de Política de privacidad](https://es.about.flipboard.com/privacy/?noredirect=es_ES)

**Como estar seguro si se necesita tener las Política de privacidad**

Responda a esta pregunta: ¿recoge alguno de los siguientes tipos de datos personales de los usuarios, en cualquier momento de su solicitud?

- Dirección de correo electrónico.
- Nombre y apellidos.
- Información de la tarjeta de crédito (normalmente almacenada por un procesador de pagos, p. Ej. PayPal, Stripe, Braintree)
- Inicios de sesión de redes sociales (Facebook, Google+)
- Información de la empresa de un cliente que posee o representa a esa
  empresa: nombre, dirección, tamaño de la empresa
- Modelos y versiones del dispositivo móvil
- Número de teléfono
- necesita acceso al Audio del dispositivo
- Otros similares

Todas estas informaciones se consideran **datos personales**. Si los datos pueden identificar a un cliente, entonces se consideran datos personales y se requiere que usted tenga una Política de privacidad.

**En resumen Su Política de privacidad debe incluir**

- Cómo recopila la información y que tipo información recopila (general)
- Cómo almacena la información
- Cómo utiliza la información personal de los usuarios.
- Si usa gestor herramientas de comunicación tipo notificaciones Push o correo electrónico
- Si usa herramientas de analítica y recopilación de información de trafico.

Sea tan claro, conciso y específico como sea posible al dejar a los usuarios saber qué información recopilan. Si necesita más consejos lea las fuentes que estan a continuación o revise ejemplos en la play store.

Fuentes: [termsfeed 1](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-mobile-apps/#Privacy_Policy_for_Android_apps), [termsfeed 2](https://termsfeed.com/blog/saas-terms-use-privacy-policy/)

Comment: Excelente informacion

Answer (score 4):

Una pregunta, por que no haces un target a dispositivos mas altos, como android 4.2 en adelante ? yo creo que te ahorrarías un problema, con respecto a la política, si tienes que dar una URL o una dirección donde ellos puedan ver las políticas de tu aplicación, ya que veo , tu app es una app que incluye chats por el GCM ( o notificaciones) , tienes que tener mucho cuidado al publicar una app de estas sin los ToS y lo de la privacidad , ya que estas tratando con la privacidad de la gente y sus dispositivos, sino imagínate la cantidad de personas que podrían tener una app con el onesignal o el gcm y llenarte de publicidad por día con las push notifications

Para asesorarte mejor puedes entrar a cualquier app que tenga muchas descargas en el store y abajo al ultimo donde dice la cantidad de descargas y el desarrollador dice "politicas de privacidad" si pinchas te lleva a la pagina del desarrollador y te muestra las politicas

**

> You use third-party services Services like Google Analytics or AdSense
>   require you to have a privacy policy stating the use of their service.

**

Espero te sirva

Comment: En mi dispositivo con android 6, se pueden bloquear las notificaciones desde configuración > aplicaciones. De hecho no conozco aplicaciones que hagan publicidad a través de notificaciones push. Gracias por responder más tarde seguiré tus consejos

Comment: si, esta bien, asegurate de pedir el permiso de las notificaciones al iniciar la app, recuerda que los permisos en android 6 deben darse adentro de la app, la cual debes programar en tu clase principal o donde desees solicitarlo, tal vez no hayas visto, pero hay mucha gente que se aprovecha de este servicio

Comment: las aplicaciones populares usan sus propios sitios web. He estado leyendo y una herramienta popular para subir las políticas es [iubenda][1] , pero no termino de configurar y me manda a una popup que dice que hay que pagar... lamentable, seguiré buscando que sitios permitan ésto.

  [1]: https://www.iubenda.com/en/privacy-policy-generator/start_modal#generator_mobile_app_modal

Answer (score 3):

En mi caso solo tuve que desmarcar la casilla de política de privacidad y colocar el link donde se puede consultar tal política, ya que tampoco utilizo algunos de los permisos que me solicita de Manifest. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]